# Cannot get LyX to produce two plots are not on same line when using knitr

Tags: r, knitr, lyx

Knitr newbie here. Love the package, and everything is going well except that two plots don't appear side-by-side once compiled in LyX.
Not sure what is going on, as I'm copying the example from the knitr graphics manual (knitr-graphics.lyx) verbatim.

My LyX code (within a Figure Float):

```
<<two-high, fig.width=3, fig.height=2.5, out.width='0.49\\linewidth'>>=
plot(cars)
boxplot(cars$dist,xlab='dist')
@
```

I can't post an image, but in the compiled pdf the plots appear under each other, not side-by-side.

My code was copied directly from the [knitr graphics manual](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/graphics/) so I don't understand why the plots are not side-by-side.

Changing the `out.width` multiplier does change the width of the plots, but at no time do they appear on the same line.

Any suggestions?

LyX Version 2.0.5.1
R version 3.0.1 
knitr 1.5

Comment: The actual code is `\begin{figure}
<<two-high, fig.width=3, fig.height=2.5, out.width='.49\\linewidth'>>=
plot(cars)
boxplot(cars$dist,xlab='dist')
@
\end{figure}`. Try adding figure environment.

Comment: Roman, I'm sorry I did not make this clear. It is already within a figure environment in LyX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There [was](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-graphics.Rnw) a global option `fig.show` set in the first chunk:

```
opts_chunk$set(fig.show='hold')
```

And that option is critical here. You may see a [simpler example here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw). Alternatively, you can use it as a local option:

```
<<two-high, fig.width=3, fig.height=2.5, fig.show='hold', out.width='0.49\\linewidth'>>=
plot(cars)
boxplot(cars$dist,xlab='dist')
@
```